# postgis update value from another table that intersects

Tags: postgis, update

I have a point table called t1 and a polygon table called t2 that are neighbourhoods.
I want to record neighbourhoods name from t2 into t1 that falls in.
My query is:
update t1 
set ti.f1 = t2.t2 
from t1 
inner join t2 on st_intersects (t1.geom, t2.geom);

[image]

this works but copy result for first record intersection into the rest of points. In this case Kitsilano.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After some tries I found the simplest way to do.

```sql
update properties_sample ps 
set name_nb = nb.name_nb
from nb 
where st_covers(nb.geom, ps.geom);
```